# ¿Cómo cambio el backgroud del un jpanel con presionar un jbotton?

Tags: java, java-swing, jframe, jbutton, jpanel

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como se muestra en la imagen, quiero seleccionar ese botton que está dentro de un panel,

como el botton es `contendAreaFilled(False)`, lo que significa que le quito el estilo.

pero tengo un problema ya que al presinar el button no sé como cambiar el color del panel, por favor necesito una ayuda

Comment: du cuál panel? puedes poner aunque sea en imágen lo que se va a cambiar de color? Por qué no pones nada de código, pretendes que rehaga todo lo que hiciste desde cero cada que preguntes?

Comment: lo que se resaltó, es un panel viejo, no importa el color cualquier color te muestro una parte de código:

Answer (score 0):

se le agrega un manejador de eventos a el botón con `addActionListener()` y dentro de el manejador usas la variable que almacena el `JPanel` y este `JPanel` debe usar luego el método `setBackgroud()`, a este metodo como argumentos se le pasa uno de los valores constantes de la clase `color`

ej:

```
varibleQueAlmacenaElJPanel.setBackgorund(Color.RED);
```